# Anomalous USB I/O errors when copying from one large external drive to another

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, hard-disk, usb-drive

Running Linux 5.4.0 under Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

I've got an issue that's driving me crazy. I recently picked up a few 12 TB external USB drives (WD MyBook 12 TB, repartitioned ext4 via gparted), with the intent of migrating from 4 TB external USB drives I'm currently using.  Under most circumstances, the 12 TB drives work fine; but under some, I get I/O errors from them.  More specifically:

- Copying the contents of a nearly-full 4 TB drive to a new 12 TB drive: no problems
- Comparing over 3 TB of data copied onto a new 12 TB drive back to the old 4 TB drive from which it came: no problems.
- Copying all of the over 3 TB of data on a new 12 TB drive to /dev/null, just as a quick read test: no problems.
- Doing those three steps above with a different new 12 TB drive: no problems.
- Copying from one of the new 12 TB drives to another of the new 12 TB drives: I/O errors out the wazoo from the source drive in the copy (the drive being read).

Again, just to make clear: the new 12 TB drives do not generate errors when I copy to them from a smaller drive, or when I read from them in a comparison with the original smaller drive, or when I read from them to copy to the bitbucket. But if I copy from one of the new drives onto another one of them, I get I/O errors.

The errors associated with the source 12 TB drive being read from look like:

```
Jan 25 00:00:25 stax kernel: [190374.338268] usb 2-6.2: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
Jan 25 00:00:25 stax kernel: [190374.418582] usb 2-6.2: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Jan 25 00:00:25 stax kernel: [190374.441059] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jan 25 00:00:25 stax kernel: [190374.441066] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 01 5e 4e d7 00 00 00 02 00 00 00
Jan 25 00:00:25 stax kernel: [190374.441073] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 5877192448 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 32 prio class 0
```

I get a non-stop stream of these errors until I ctrl-c the copy. I've googled these error messages, and the usual consensus is that these are associated with a failing drive. But ignoring the fact that they're brand new (since new drives do sometimes come broken), badblocks returns no problems with either of the new 12 TB drives, and they work perfectly fine in every way so long as I'm not trying to copy from one of the new drives to another of the new drives. In particular, they work fine when copying to/from smaller drives I already had.

In all cases, the drives used are attached to powered USB hubs, which are then attached to physical ports on the computer.  I've tried putting the two 12 TB drives on the same hub, as well as on different hubs that are themselves connected to physical USB ports associated with different USB controllers on the motherboard.

This is so bizarre to me, and I'm at a loss on how to proceed. Any advice would be very helpful.

Comment: so, in summary, the error occurs only when *using* (i.e. read one, write the other) two of the 12TB drives at the same time?

Comment: Correct.  But they don't have to be on the same hub, or even controller.

Comment: what the VID:PID of these drives? have you searched for any known issues with having two of these on the one (linux) system - if you boot up, then connect the drives one by one, is there anything in the system logs that may provide a clue to your issue?

Comment: 1058:25ed for both.  I didn't see anything about having two of these on the system in a google.  The output to syslog from successive physical connections looks identical, except for (of course) the drive serial numbers.  The only complaints of any kind are the "diagnostic page" messages that (as I understand it) are typical because the query to the drive comes before the drive has finished spinning up yet.

Comment: A little more info:  I've tried using Y-connectors for the device cable's connection to the USB hub, trying to improve the power situation.  Still no joy.